Action required - 4 deep links may be failing because your web domains aren't associated with your app - How to add multiple domain in deeplinking
We have 4 common domains and each client has these 4 for production and testing (Live, sandbox, etc).
For example:
Our clients are ABC and DEF, we have url as
live.domain.com/abc
sandbox.domain.com/abc

live.domain.com/def
sandbox.domain.com/def

My question is how do we add all to deeplinking, and the url only works with client name in it. Also we cant show client domainn to each other. in android we need to manually enable domain url in settings. Any suggestion would be helpful.
